# "Multi-level" network resource names. Corresponding names of DNS servers

Tags: dns

(If I understand) when my application wishes to communicate with a network resource over IP the basic steps if DNS is used to resolve (?) / the name to an IP address are as follows (*).

Consider a 3 level resource name: www.goodeggs.edu

- Local host asks ISP DNS server(?) to resolve name to IP address. Not found.
- Resource name is read from right-to-left.
- ISP DNS Server asks ROOT Server "which server knows about.edu?" and gets IP address of TLD Server that knows about ".edu"
- ISP server asks .edu TLD Server for the server that knows about ".goodeggs.org". TLD Server returns to ISP the address of the NAME server for ".goodeggs.org".
- ISP asks ".goodeggs.org" NAME Server for the address of the actual resource, www.goodeggs.edu. NAME server returns address of resource to ISP DNS Server which forwards IP of resource to the local host application.

In summary:

- ISP DNS Server connects to following servers in following order
- ROOT (for .edu)
- TLD (for goodeggs.edu)
- NAME (for www.goodeggs.edu) << Resource IP Address from here

THE QUESTION !

What if my resource name has more than three nodes e.g.

www.bbc.co.uk ?

Are the servers named

- ROOT (for .uk)
- TLD1 (for co.uk)
- TLD2 (for .bbc.co.uk)
- NAME (for www.bbc.co.uk) << Resource IP Address from here

(* I am writing this down, although someone may (will) complain (such is S.E.) it is not a question, I am asking if my basic understanding of DNS is correct - or not.)

Comment: I answered this a while ago [over here](https://superuser.com/a/477316/113356). In short, the IP address is provided by an "authoritative" server, not by the number of levels of subdomain. The root servers answer for the ROOT, which is `.` (dot). Subdomains under the root are top-level domains, for which registries provide references to any level of subdomain under them.

Comment: Hi, I did read your account earlier, but it seemed at odds with other descriptions of the operation of DNS and I could not grasp the idea of an "authoritative" server. Is my research and account of ROOT > TLD > NAME servers completely wrong? I don't see how this fits with your description - but I may well be missing the link - as I can't find TLD or NAME servers discussed in your posting. I am struggling to reconcile the accounts. Thanks.

Comment: Patrick has covered it for you. Yay Patrick!

Answer (score 1):

There are several deficiencies in your description, so first correct that.

Today, QNAME minimization is not the norm, which means the whole name is asked at each step, it is not broken up by label.

so, in short:

1. you query a recursive nameserver
2. if it has the answer in its local cache and the TTL has not expired, it replies directly to you, end of the story
3. if not, it starts the recursive process for you: starting at the root it asks for the name; each authoritative nameserver not being authoritative for the name will instead give back a list of NS record to go ask next (and this will also all be cached), and so on, until one nameserver replies authoritatively for your specific request, in which case the recursive nameserver job has ended, it stores the reply in its cache and then gives it to you too.

You can use `dig +trace` option to see it, for example:

```
$ dig +trace www.bbc.co.uk

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> +trace www.bbc.co.uk
;; global options: +cmd
.           352520 IN NS l.root-servers.net.
.           352520 IN NS c.root-servers.net.
.           352520 IN NS d.root-servers.net.
.           352520 IN NS a.root-servers.net.
.           352520 IN NS j.root-servers.net.
.           352520 IN NS f.root-servers.net.
.           352520 IN NS h.root-servers.net.
.           352520 IN NS m.root-servers.net.
.           352520 IN NS g.root-servers.net.
.           352520 IN NS k.root-servers.net.
.           352520 IN NS e.root-servers.net.
.           352520 IN NS b.root-servers.net.
.           352520 IN NS i.root-servers.net.
.           444986 IN RRSIG NS 8 0 518400 (
                20180523050000 20180510040000 39570 .
                iCesuUeD36Re2VEdzRbmFh28kIeNo/Qpb0fi8r1/vu79
                ShjbkB1j2ySalLUYt1AgYQegkU/62/bw+G9i1hbFDGu3
                zvbr+VDxQWHX5tkeXNz0+JujJ/ITfFItTSD8LSmXyJcF
                QP6YNwNQ5f5WzBy4SiURgXCYhyOrcviIlXOa+9QuEpE+
                kGj/NZp2YNR6CMWhv0ImOgwdzZG8gF83LM6a/RLoaFG1
                6EwWBgrhZksnUzHS9Hv3MKVpIZMGnQA/QRUJMB+LyZeQ
                CcnWoAzchGTVxmTf6Wlhdj+MhuaQ656KMxbTaPrGzjfr
                vyYq6KmIrto/kS9Rc9NsaV6IA7fLqxvaIw== )
;; Received 1097 bytes from 192.168.10.229#53(192.168.10.229) in 2 ms

uk.         172800 IN NS dns1.nic.uk.
uk.         172800 IN NS dns4.nic.uk.
uk.         172800 IN NS nsa.nic.uk.
uk.         172800 IN NS nsd.nic.uk.
uk.         172800 IN NS nsc.nic.uk.
uk.         172800 IN NS nsb.nic.uk.
uk.         172800 IN NS dns3.nic.uk.
uk.         172800 IN NS dns2.nic.uk.
uk.         86400 IN DS 43876 8 2 (
                A107ED2AC1BD14D924173BC7E827A1153582072394F9
                272BA37E2353BC659603 )
uk.         86400 IN RRSIG DS 8 1 86400 (
                20180524050000 20180511040000 39570 .
                YisP01VEWwakIJeUgDGu+JkWdbEe6DHYwvboX9ngd95e
                rbZb3EeDU3ieS8x+qcGWpmXtwLnec2A2aoBvXTZjLdP3
                a01mIdOSzlBLXJz6ejXKRyc1/a7DkxxtzCZTa89JVbGy
                lIwgCxS/CXdo2A3M+sc7YGBd14XgTu0l1Z1ZZMm9ZWF3
                W3gjdKDiGMKFRolZbxyhUwacIhaxIOFsgkHfKiGyONe1
                Qx8O1kIy0NhMKOYcw05183tTO4zd1w1UJRidr1jyVwFl
                i+UhL5nVsXOwh1HaeiiIMwLLXVeP2d5ISaO/2dA4KEhZ
                wC3KPlJvl3gF8e7fiEs6OrbYgCmvZ7o3VQ== )
;; Received 797 bytes from 198.41.0.4#53(a.root-servers.net) in 139 ms

bbc.co.uk.      172800 IN NS ns4.bbc.net.uk.
bbc.co.uk.      172800 IN NS ns3.bbc.net.uk.
bbc.co.uk.      172800 IN NS ns3.bbc.co.uk.
bbc.co.uk.      172800 IN NS ns4.bbc.co.uk.
G9F1KIIHM8M9VHJK7LRVETBQCEOGJIQP.co.uk. 10800 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - (
                G9HKV8PHGJ1NMH94L9RMIQM0J64UCIPK
                NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
                TYPE65534 )
G9F1KIIHM8M9VHJK7LRVETBQCEOGJIQP.co.uk. 10800 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 3 10800 (
                20180614141322 20180510140235 33621 co.uk.
                j1bmaifCFfs1u84HWglaeTxZLTAd4b+a7Lr/1+JwrrcB
                7TlQhEPkbgTIaLUUkySPJfxY+tdkfaRFrzbheLgXbE+u
                qSOmuHxhuhHSFsDhaYfEbSCaWB/J+7JKgQOSHbhVnF0m
                rD7DMDKbYTcalNNB0VlTdhiSumd0oGyqohugqvw= )
TP2SFUK8GL59V3TCVHK2DBGOD4LP2VPK.co.uk. 10800 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - (
                TP40D2GKG41E62VT49B179FKD8QU8D56
                NS DS RRSIG )
TP2SFUK8GL59V3TCVHK2DBGOD4LP2VPK.co.uk. 10800 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 3 10800 (
                20180610203629 20180506202704 33621 co.uk.
                AdiIoWpWjQuUGMqLvWbKidEGsw86ZUTgJFZjeO6qfYKr
                MlbkII+8dm6kp2EZsMRuzRcP6/pUYDK0rn99Rmx5JRsj
                ISLeyDG4kM2/eDMxfObZEe1zZSxIxoZmRzV6ZWJ3QIFt
                9zFT2hq7eLQfHJKzZ8unzsl8r2l6xrncSUsNZxs= )
;; Received 733 bytes from 156.154.102.3#53(nsc.nic.uk) in 74 ms

www.bbc.co.uk.      300 IN CNAME www.bbc.net.uk.
;; Received 68 bytes from 156.154.65.17#53(ns4.bbc.net.uk) in 73 ms
```

You see exactly which nameservers are queried, starting from the root, and the replies, first only `NS` records chaining authoritative nameservers from one "level" to the next (ignore `RRSIG` and `NSEC3` records, but make extra care to watch the `;; Received` lines to show exactly which nameserver replied what), and finally the reply.

You have online troubleshooting tools that will give you the same information with nice images with blocks and arrows, for example:
http://dnsviz.net/d/www.bbc.co.uk/WvW_7Q/dnssec/
(a little complicated because of the final `CNAME`)

So the problem is not exactly the number of dots. Zone cut does not necessarily happen at each dot. For example `gouv.fr` and `fr` are in the same zone, there is no zone cut, the authoritative nameservers for `gouv.fr` are the same than for `fr`. This is a design choice.

TLD is a loose term. It is often a synonym of right most label but this is not always true. In the past you could register only `.co.uk` domain names, registration directly under `.uk` was not possible. In that case you could say `.co.uk` was the TLD. There are many registries still working with subdomains like that. You have also cases with multiple different registries at different levels: for example you can register domains under `.com` and under `.uk.com`, both handled by different "registries" (they can be talk there about the business side of it, but I am only focusing on the technical side of it, illustrating that the DNS is like a tree, everything can happen technically at the same node, irrelevant to how deep it is). You can say then that `.uk.com` is a SLD for *Second Level Domain (Name)*. However other registries can be at the third level, and so on (for example in the past `.US` was very deep, with at least 4 or 5 levels at least to encode the US State, then the county, then the type of school, etc. you can see many examples on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.us)